# Change column width in SharePoint Online list

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

It hurts me to have to ask this question here, but one full day of searching through the internet didn't get us an answer so far.

[image: screenshot]

Like you can see, the content is stuck on the left side.
Adding the CSS `.od-ClientFormFields-fieldsContainer {
 max-width:100% !important;
}` didn't have any effect. It does still limit the max-width to 378px. I just want to strech it to full width. Just this list, just on this page. Coming from PHP, I expected 5 minutes work max. Now a day is lost and I hate MS a little more...

Update:
in my display form (DispForm.aspx), I added my style from above below the given style:

```
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
 padding: 8px;
 border: none;
}
```

In this form, I can see just some lines (108) of code. Am I looking in the wrong place? I tried to create a new DisplayForm, but in the end it was nasty. The list was placed centered and didn't work properly. I couldn't even edit it.
Plus I've had another menu there, which I didn't have in my original DispForm.aspx, just "edit all". At that point, I stopped. I just want the list to be wider.
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Which CSS classes are applied to the element, according to the developer tools? Which class overrides the one you changed? SharePoint CSS can be nasty. Don't expect an easy fix.

Comment: According to the developer tools, the class "od-ClientFormFields-fieldsContainer" has a max-width of 378px. If I remove that within the developer tools, the result does look okay. I was horrified when I saw "solutions" I found via google, where they added js to modify the css on page load. I tried clicking almost any button I could find within the Designer and to add the above css everywhere where I saw an css option or any other css (including within the code of the .aspx file itself).